# How to convert State to useState hook in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I converted a class component to function component. The issue is that I need to convert this.setState to useState hook. I'm trying to figure out how to change the following to the useState hook

```
state = {
    services: {},
  };

zeroconf.on('resolved', data => {
   this.setState({
          services: {
            ...this.state.services [data.host]: data,
          },
        });
}
```

I need to convert to useState hook but not sure how.
Below is what I have tried

```
const [services, setServices] = useState({});

zeroconf.on('resolved', data => {
  setServices(services:{...services [data.host]: data})
```

zeroconf.on('resolved', data) is a event listener and the information from data is:

```
{
  "port": 51484,
  "txt": {},
  "addresses": [
    "127.0.0.1",
    "::1",
    "fe80::1",
    "192.168.0.10",
    "fe80::46e"
  ],
  "name": "printer",
  "fullName": "Book-Pro.local._printer._tcp.",
  "host": "Book-Pro.local."
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just feed it the object, and take in the argument to get the most up to date value of `services`.

```js
const [services, setServices] = useState({});

zeroconf.on('resolved', data => {
  setServices(currentServices => ({...currentServices, [data.host]: data}));
});
```

Comment: I notice that because the state starts as {} useState({});   Inside of my list I get 1 empty object. is there anything I can do to remove the empty object